# Which model of arduino to use for a solenoid based output project?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I am a software developer with no prior experience in embedded programming & electronics. I have to build a project that requires microcontrollers inclusion.

The task is kind of(example) I need to generate Morse Code pulses which are to be output through a solenoid in the form of vibrations. I would also like to use c/c++ as coding language. I made a search & found arduino more suitable for this task with my exposure to this field.

I would be grateful if you guys please comment on suitablility of it for this task. & also refer which model of arduino should I use. I am thinking to use any 8-bit variant of arduinio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not have almost any requirements - buy the cheapest one with integrated programmer.
Maybe one of those?
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano
http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMicro

Comment: This is a start of project. Its like a prototype but requirment may grow later, let's say something like wifi output. So should this be OK what you suggested with that too ? 
I was provided with Raspberry PI model B controllers with 4 GB SD card but I did not found them much user friendly & Python is also no prefererd tool for me.

Comment: It depends what you want to do exactly. The Arduino will be small enough to fit in a small box, it can be powered easily and will be able to do some more things than RBP (measuring analog value, generating PWM at 1MHz...). On the other hand RBP is easier to extend with WiFi and to write the software just like on a normal computer.

Comment: Actually I have decided to go for arduino. Just was asking if your suggested one arduino variant are good for expanding requirements too. Or you may refer some other with more capabilities. Bec I have to just jump start & want to concenrate on development once I selected/got one. What about this kit as it is available from store: http://store.mansteri.com/index.php/en/arduino/arduino-boards/starter-kit-arduino-leonardo.html

Comment: The bigger boards have those two rows of sockets. Using them you can add "shields" which add new features like ethernet, bluetooth and so on. If you just want to control a relay - take the simplest one.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter which Arduino you use since your requirements seem very simple. The Uno is fine.

As for controlling solenoids, it is very easy using a transistor like the TIP120 - see this [tutorial](http://bildr.org/2011/03/high-power-control-with-arduino-and-tip120/) (and there are many others - just search for "arduino solenoid"). Be aware that you can't (shouldn't) power a solenoid directly from the Arduino.

As for using C/C++ - you can do that with the Arduino since it's Wiring language is C/C++ based. You can write in C/C++ or use Wiring. You can also set things up to use Eclipse if the barebones Arduino IDE is too primitive compared to what you may be used to.

Finally, the [Arduino forums](http://arduino.cc/forum/) are the best place to ask questions - huge, friendly community.