# Arduino Leonardo OR Uno for a pototype solenoid project ??

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I am a software developer with no prior experience in embedded programming. I have to develop a prototype project:(example) to generate Morse Code pulses which are to be output through a solenoid in the form of vibrations. I found that either Arduino Nano or Micro will do this job. Though I have choosen Uno for the project keeping in view later requiremenst will evolve.

I found Leonardo & Uno two close varianst. I selected Uno based on some research I did. Mainly I learned Leonardo is not good choice for beginners due to some of its problems and/or features. Uno also has more help available too being a seasoned variant.

It will be nice if I can have some opinion about it.

Comment: Question might be better placed on http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I can only share my own experience introducing myself to AVR. I just bought a couple of ATmega8's (in case I burn one :), soldered some resistors and LEDs, crystal and voltage regulator, made very simple programmer over LPT port and was good to go (reading Atmel's datasheet).

Comment: For a prototype, Uno is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you and [Keshav Saharia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215918/arduino-leonardo-or-uno-for-a-pototype-solenoid-project#comment23206790_16215918) said, assuming that the capabilities of Uno and Leonardo both meet your needs, the reason to choose the Uno is because it is older, more mature, and better supported. For example, most of the Arduino posts here and on [EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) are either based on Uno or are compatible with Uno. Likewise, most of the Arduino guides work out-of-the-box with Uno, but not necessarily with Leonardo; Leonardo is always one of those footnotes: If you have Leonardo, you need to do *this other thing* instead.

Also, if, at some point, you decide to ditch Arduino and use a bare ATmega chip, ATmega328, the MPU in the Uno is the one you are likely to use, and also the one more people are familiar with. Leonardo uses a different AVR chip, the ATmega32u4, which, like the Leonardo, is not quite as popular (widespread?). These are good reasons to choose the Uno, as far as I am concerned.

On the other hand, if you are hoping to keep the prototype board for yourself, you might want to think about the Leonardo, since it is more powerful: more IO, second hardware serial port, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You already asked this question and it has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16096154/840992). Your conclusion that the Arduino Nano or Micro won't do the job is wrong. Any version of Arduino will work, as will any other microcontroller (Basic Stamp, Picaxe, etc.). All you need to do to control a solenoid is to turn a digital pin from LOW to HIGH. You **WILL** need some external circuitry because of solenoid power requirements but the circuitry is trivial.

Comment: Actually bec I was not specific in that post about any variant of arduino. Thanks for your input about Nano & Micro. I realized that too but actually I am also looking one competing Rasberry Pi B so I found these two models of arduino.